# Android maps v2 showInfoWindow() causes crash, at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker.showInfoWindow(Unknown Source)

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

Friends,

has anyone an idea why the marker.showInfoWindow() method crashes? with the following error code.
Everything works fine when i don´t use that method, all markers are clickable in the map and all the custom info windows appear on screen on user click just as desired.

Thanks for any help

```
private void addGoogleMapAdvertisementMarker(ValueObjectAdvertiserData valueObjectAdvertiserData) {

    // adds a single advertisement marker to the map and
    // stores the individual marker to the arraylist markers
   Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(valueObjectAdvertiserData.latitude, valueObjectAdvertiserData.longitude))
            .title(valueObjectAdvertiserData.headline)
            .snippet(valueObjectAdvertiserData.description)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));
    marker.showInfoWindow();

    markers.add(marker);
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
04-17 19:09:58.540  25708-25708/il.co.shabeng.SLDMP E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: il.co.shabeng.SLDMP, PID: 25708
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{il.co.shabeng.SLDMP/il.co.shabeng.SLDMP.ActivityMain}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2328)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at il.co.shabeng.SLDMP.ActivityMain$1.getInfoContents(ActivityMain.java:244)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$13.zzg(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzd$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
            at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.p.b(SourceFile:112)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.h.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.h.a(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.h.b(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.c.j.c(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.aj.g(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.internal.t.onTransact(SourceFile:145)
            at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:361)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.internal.zzl$zza$zza.showInfoWindow(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker.showInfoWindow(Unknown Source)
            at il.co.shabeng.SLDMP.ActivityMain.addGoogleMapAdvertisementMarker(ActivityMain.java:204)
            at il.co.shabeng.SLDMP.ActivityMain.placeAdMarkersOnMap(ActivityMain.java:169)
            at il.co.shabeng.SLDMP.ActivityMain.onCreate(ActivityMain.java:106)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2386)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5476)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: There's a NullPointerException at il.co.shabeng.SLDMP.ActivityMain$1.getInfoContents(ActivityMain.java:244). Please post the code around this location.

Comment: Thanks! that was it. In line 244 there was an if statement thats analysing another marker ( userlocationmarker ) that got instanciated later on in the code. The showInfoWindow() triggered the method getInfoContents() before i expected it to be triggerd. thanks again